# How does one get tomcat to bind to ipv4 address?

Tags: tomcat6, solr, typo3

I recently installed tomcat via an installation script from the apache solr typo3 community and spent the last 3 days trying to figure out why it won't work until by chance I noticed that when I queried the process listening on the port via "`lsof -i`", it was bound to the ipv6 protocol.

I have googled everywhere and most say that setting address to **`0.0.0.0`** in the tomcat connector resolves this issue, others say setting **`JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"`**.

I have tried the former which doesn't work but the latter I am unsure of where to put it. One solution I read somewhere suggested to put it in **`setenv.sh`** but I can't find this file in my tomcat installation. I would appreciate any help at the moment regarding this.

The tomcat version is 6.x and the OS is ubuntu 11.10.

Thanks

Comment: What ips/ports is it listening on, via lsof -i?

Comment: @becomingwisest 8080.

Comment: You are correct - setenv.sh file does not exist out of box. You need to create setenv.sh file in your CATALINA_BASE or CATALINA_HOME bin directory. The startup scripts check if you created the file, if you did create customization (setenv.sh) file - startup script calls it, otherwise just ignores, and moves on.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Many suggested updating `catalina.sh` startup script. Yes, that solution would work, but `catalina.sh` script is not meant to be customized/updated. All changes should go into the customization script instead, i.e. `setenv.sh`.

NOTE: `TOMCAT_HOME/bin/setenv.sh` doesn't exist by default, you need to create it. Check the `catalina.sh` script and you will see the startup script checks if `setenv.sh` exists, and executes if it does.

So, I suggest you create new `TOMCAT_HOME/bin/setenv.sh` script with a single line:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true "
```

Comment: I would also use CATALINA_OPTS instead of JAVA_OPTS, especially if you have other JVM options you want to pass into JVM on Tomcat startup. If you use JAVA_OPTS, the same options will be passed into Tomcat shutdown, probably not what you would want/expect. Use CATALINA_OPTS instead :)

Comment: I'm choosing this as the answer now since most people having this issue today would most likely be using a newer version of tomcat.

Answer (score 28):

Ok I finally solved it. I was directed to [try this](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianIPv6#How_to_turn_off_IPv6) and Henk's solution. Neither of which seemed to work with the remote virtual server. I'm guessing the fact that because I'm on a shared kernel space so the provider prevents this. In any case I added: `JAVA_OPTS= $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses` to the catalina.sh startup script and that seemed to have fixed the issue of binding tomcat to ipv6.

Comment: So you're on a VPS with a shared kernel... D'oh!

Comment: This seems not to work anymore with tomcat 8.

Comment: With tomcat 8, this option didn't work for me, but nevenc's answer did work.

Answer (score 5):

The correct syntax for modifying catalina.sh would be:

```
JAVA_OPTS=" $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true "
```

Answer (score 3):

If you used this installer: "[Apache Solr for TYPO3](http://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-solr/wiki/Setup_on_*NIX)", you can change the address in the file `server.xml`. The default points to localhost, so look for 127.0.0.1 and change it into the IPv4-address you want. Don't forget to restart Tomcat6 for the changes to take effect.

#### *UPDATE, 20120521*

See my comment below on how to disable IPv6 on Ubuntu 11.10.

I have successfully tested this on a Virtualbox-VM on my Mac. The address for the connector port 8080 has been changed from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 in `server.xml`.

Then disabling IPv6 makes the "tcp6" to go away, so it's binded to an IPv4-only address.

Before / with IPv6 enabled:

```
# netstat -anp | grep 8080   
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1972/java
```

After / IPv6 disabled:

```
# netstat -anp | grep 8080   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2045/java
```

Comment: Tried this also and that didn't work netstat shows that despite the process being bound to an ipv4 address it's still looking for an ipv6 a la this return: tcp6       0      0 X.X.X.X:8080       :::*                    LISTEN. which I think is odd but the problem has also been replicated on my friend's vm which is hosted on a mac.

Comment: And when IPv6 is disabled? Here is a howto for Ubuntu 11.10: http://pario.no/2011/12/09/disable-ipv6-on-ubuntu-11-10/

Answer (score 1):

While probably not the preferred method, I have observed that [disabling IPv6 at the kernel level](https://askubuntu.com/a/337736/236574) will convince Tomcat to open an IPv4 bind.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Java Options have been set to disable IPv4:

```
JAVA_OPTS=" $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true"
```

Using Tomcat SSL with APR, the only way I could get Tomcat to bind to ipv4  was to add this to the connector config:

```
address="0.0.0.0"
```

server.xml looks like this:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150"
               SSLEnabled="true"
               scheme="https"
               compression="off"
               connectionTimeout="1190"
               address="0.0.0.0"
               >
```

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: Did you use the preferIPv4Stack Java Opts arg when starting?

Comment: Yes. I had to disable IPV6 in redhat to fix this.

Answer (score -2):

Debian 8 navigate to  using your favorite editor on **/etc/default/grub** ; look for the section **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT**="quiet"** with then add **ipv6.disable=1**, as seen below

**GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 quiet"**

Save and exit.
In the same directory use your favorite editor on **/etc/default/tomcat8** then look for the section with **JAVA_OPTS=** which will be commented out, add the following below that line. **JAVA_OPTS=" $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true"**

Save and exit

At the command prompt type **update-grub** , if you have sudo use with sudo, then restart tomcat8  **service tomcat8 restart**

You should be on IPv4 now.

Please in future posts include complete paths and file names.
Thank You