# Connections Timed Out - Tomcat

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tomcat

I'm having a problem with Tomcat:

On a clean install, connecting to [ip-address]:8080 times out.

I have seen many similar questions and tried basically everything there, with no success. But here is all my data related to similar problems:

Version: Tomcat 7

Linux: Ubuntu

iptables -L output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

netstat -nat | grep :8080 output

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

telnet localhost 8080 output

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

telnet [ip-address] 8080 output

```
Trying [ip-address]... (this seems to go on forever)
```

I feel like I must be missing something incredibly obvious, as I have not added any WARs/made any modifications to the server except installing java and tomcat.
Below is my Server.xml (comments removed):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />

  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443" address="0.0.0.0"  />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: Is there a network firewall in the way?  Are you using a VPS or something?

Comment: Are you connecting to the server's IPv4 or IPv6 address? Your `netstat` output does not indicate that it's listening to 8080 on a v4 address.

Comment: Tomcat is binding to IPv6.  Take a look at this previous question and answers, it may help.  http://serverfault.com/questions/390840/how-does-one-get-tomcat-to-bind-to-ipv4-address

Comment: Kudos for the extensive collection of diagnostic info.  At this stage, I'd break out `tcpdump` to make sure that traffic is flowing where it should be flowing, and also looking at the `netstat -atn` output to see what state the connection is in, exactly.  SYN_SENT vs SYN_ACK might be instructive.

Comment: @Gene Unless it's binding with v6only, it'll work fine on IPv4 connections using v4-mapped addresses.  Also, if it were connecting to an unbound address, you'd see ECONNREFUSED immediately rather than the connection hang.

Comment: @FalconMomot I am on a VPS (Amazon EC2 instance). There does not appear to be a firewall (see the iptables output)

Comment: @Gene I have been connecting to the IPv4 (but also using the Amazon supplied DNS lookup). I'll try that solution and edit my question accordingly.

Comment: @womble hey thanks. I try to only ask quality questions when possible.

Comment: @womble, thank you, I was not aware of that.  I haven't done much with IPv6 (we disable it).  Guess I'll have to get out some reading material. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are on Amazon EC2, and it's working local to the instance but not to its IP address, check your host's network ACL (i.e. security group).  The wizard guides you to set up a very restrictive policy, and if you try to do something like open up HTTP to the world, it will just open inbound port 80.

Comment: This was it! I knew when I set up those rules they would come back to bite me. I had totally forgotten about them.

Thanks! (I will, of course, mark yours as "answer" in 4 minutes).